# ColdFusion ReReplace

Tags: regex, coldfusion

What I'm trying to do is add forward slash to the beginning and end of a string of text if the first and last character of the string is not `/`.

In my script I have:

```
if(!reFind('\/\S\/', myString){
    myString = '/' & arrayToList(listToArray(myString, '/\'), '/') & '/');
}
```

I want to run a ReReplace instead of listing to an array and then adding the slashes in.

Comment: What does "instead of listing to an array" mean?

Comment: Sounds like you're fiddling with directories/paths. Read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem then come back and **explain your actual problem** and we can help with an _appropriate_ solution (which may or not involve ListChangeDelims instead of your ArrayToList/ListToArray hack).

Comment: I am fiddling with directory paths. This is for internal use so that when I add new controllers and views to my MVC filesystem I know that they are working properly. Essentially, I want to enter a string and not have to be concerned about remembering the forward slashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using array to list and list to array could possibly remove inner slashes, so you don't want to do that. Instead, replace leading and trailing slashes with a regex.

```
<cfscript>
    string1 = "foobar";
    string2 = "/foobar/";
    string3 = "foo/bar";
    string4 = "/foo/bar/";

    function addSlashes (str) {
        return "/" & reReplace(str,"^/|/$","","all") & "/";
    }

    writeDump(addSlashes(string1));
    writeDump(addSlashes(string2));
    writeDump(addSlashes(string3));
    writeDump(addSlashes(string4));
</cfscript>
```

you can paste the above into http://www.trycf.com

Comment: Thank you. This does exactly what I want it to do via regular expressions. Also, thanks for the resource!

Comment: @Curtis Adam's answer does it in 2 less steps. If one or both of these answers answer your question, be sure to accept one or the other by clicking the checkmark under the answer vote score.

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to replace `^/?(.*?)/?$` with `/\1/`.

See a visual explanation at [http://www.regexper.com/](http://www.regexper.com/#%5E%5C/?%28.%2a?%29%5C/?%24)

Note the pattern I use @ www.regexper.com is slightly different as I need to escape the `/` for a JS pattern; not so with CFML ones.